# Precising if statement in awk

Tags: awk

Is that possible to precise conditions in "if" statement? Let's take an example from my previous post (by the way, "k" variable is tricky, thanks terdon;)) and say that I'm looking for $i which starts from two capital letter, after that we have 2 digits, other letters/digits are not important and lenght of the word which I'm looking for is not constant (in example: AB12asdf or HR56Ame4).

> awk '{k=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
>
> ```
>         if ($i=="ABC"){print $(i-2); k++}
>        } 
>        if(k==0){print "No ABC in line",NR}
>  }' file.txt
> ```

Thanks,

lucas

Comment: You can be as precise as the condition you write matches on. `/^[[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/` will match two upper-case letters followed by two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `~` regex-match operator

```
if ($i ~ /^[[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/)
```